# Excel Sumifs Index Match returning only value

Tags: excel

Trying to use a combination of SUMIFS, INDEX and MATCH but the formula only returns a value from the first column and ignores subsequent columns which share the same field.  What formula can I use to overcome this issue please?

```
         A          B   C   D   E   F
1   Name           Week1    Week1   Week2   Week2   Year
2   CustomerA   10  20  30  40  2019
3   CustomerB   50  60  70  80  2019
4   CustomerA   90  100 110 120 2018
5   CustomerB   130 140 150 160 2018
```

I have to get the Week 1 Total for Customer A in 2019.

I tried using this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B:E,0,MATCH("Week1",B1:E1,0)), A:A,"CustomerA", F:F, "2019")
```

The formula however, only returns $10 for Customer A in Week 1 in 2019 instead of $30 ($10 from Cell B2 + $20 from cell C2).  This means it matches the Week 1 field in column B and ignores the Week 1 field in column C.

What amendment do I need to make to the formula to overcome this problem please?
Thanks.

[image: Image of the Excel Table]

Answer (score 2):

That method will only work if the values are unique, as it will only return the first column where a match is found.

You will need SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$E$1="Week1")*($A$2:$A$5 = "CustomerA")*($F$2:$F$5 = 2019)*($B$2:$E$5))
```

[image]

Comment: i have a quick question for you. Why do you use `*($B$2:$F$5)` instead of `*($B$2:$E$5))`

Comment: True, since F is a criteria and not a value it can be changed to `E`.  @Error1004.